# 外部mp4ファイル(複数)のPHPによるダウンロードがうまく出来ない

Tags: php

#### 前提・実現したいこと

PHPで、外部ファイルのmp4のURLを複数取得し、ループさせ、１つずつダウンロードしたい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

samp;e1.mp4 sample2.mp4 sample3.mp4とダウンロードされるはずが
sample1.mp4だけがダウンロードされ、しかもファイルサイズが巨大になる。(２～以降の分も入っている？)
そして、その動画も壊れているようで再生できない。

些細なことでもお分かりの方がいましたら、助かります。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
<?php
$c = 1;
foreach( $urls as $url){
    $header = get_headers($url, 1);
    mb_http_output("pass");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.$header['Content-Length']);
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="sample'.$c.'.mp4"');
    $c = $c + 1; 
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb');
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $buf = fread($fp, 1048576);
        echo $buf;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($fp);  
}
?>
```

#### 試したこと

ループ処理にせず、単一のURLだけ指定するとうまくダウンロードでき、動画も再生できる。
URLは正しく取得できていることはログで確認済みです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

php7です。
linux環境です。

Comment: Webサーバからの応答はヘッダとボディに分かれており、ヘッダは1セットしか指定できません。PHPの場合一度ボディ部を出力してしまう(あなたのコードなら`echo $buf`)と、以降の`header`関数の呼び出しはエラー終了します。自分で特殊なプロトコルを編み出すつもりでない限り、1回のリクエストに対しては1つの画像しか返せません。繰り返しはあなたのPHPサーバを呼び出すクライアントの方で工夫した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: このコードだと、レスポンスは3つの動画ファイルがくっついて帰ってくることになるとおもいます。すこし情報を足すなどしてクライアント側で分割してあげないといけません。あと複数回ヘッダーを出力していますが、OOPerさんが書かれているとおり、echoとflushで一度Bodyデータを返してしまうと、以降のヘッダーは無視されます。次の質問の回答が参考になるでしょう。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5453/php-%E3%81%AE-headers-already-sent-%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E7%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/143594

Comment: 皆様、ありがとうございました。